# Using an if formula in order to write in other cell

Tags: vba, if-statement, formula

I have one cell with a drop list with three values (open, close, pending). I want to make a formula to make sure that when an issue is reported the status change to open. With this formula `=if("e2<>0,"open","")` work without any problem but i don't want to change the value of the cells with the drop list so i need something like this `=if("e2<>0,i2="open","")`.

Is there a way to do this without using vba? And how could i make it with vba if i want to update in live? when i put any data in e2 i2 should be open without the need to reopen the file.

Comment: Any particular reason why you do not want to insert the formula directly into the cell you want to change (in this case, `I2`)?

Comment: Because is a drop list with three values (open closed pending) and i want that anyone that use the sheet can change it. The only reason i want to do this now is because ppl forget to put in the status "open" and there is a filter already made to show every issue that is still open or pending so if ppl forget is going to be a problem. If i put the formula in the same cell the drop list would be lost or is it a way to do it so the person who use it only see the drop list and the formula is in place too? Thanks

Comment: =IF(AND(E2<>0,I2="open"),"","") like something like this?

Comment: Even though I understand your point, wouldn't that harm the correctness of the data? Suppose the user wants to change the value of the cell to "pending" and you have that code in place, it will soon change it to "open", compromising the whole data. You shouldn't allow the user to change something that is supposed to be changed automatically. If you want to make sure the data is inserted and you know which data it should be, just put the formula in the cell and lock it so the user won't mess with it

Comment: True but if i know how to do that if i put later more conditions for example if there is data in e2 and i2 isn't closed or pending put open (At least i hope ill manage :D) PS: Going to try with that one thx ricky

Comment: It didn't work with that one but using AND i can do what i wanted to but i have the same issue, it would affect only the cell where the formula is and not the one i want to change

Comment: If you have more conditions, you just add more conditions. Something like `=If(AND(E2<>0,AND(NOT(I2="closed"),NOT(I2="pending"))),"open","")` *(definitely not tested)*. Sorry, but I still don't see your point. If you know when the value should be "open", when to be "pending" and when to be "closed", why give this responsibility to the user?

Comment: Because the user is the tech that have to say if it is pending close or open and the problem is not the conditions the problem is that i want to have the formula in other cell not in the one that the drop list is. Unless is a way to have the formula and the user only see the drop list in that cell. The perfect way would be conditional formatting but i want to put a value so i cant use that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use VBA

in the relevant worksheet code pane put this code

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Excel.Range) 
    If Target.Address = "$E$2" And Target.Value <> 1 Then Range("I2").Value = "open"
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks. Works ill make it as a loop so it take the column and play around to put it the rest of the conditions. So it isn't possible with a formula then?

Comment: Hmm I tried to put more conditions but it doesn't work that way, is not possible to put another if inside that one or put another and at the end? i want to check if is already write "closed" or "pending" in i2

Comment: explain in more detail what's your goal

Comment: I want to write in i2 "open" whenever something is write on e2 (that part is working perfect with that code) but in order to write "open" on i2 that cell cant be already filled with "closed" or "pending". So i need to check if it is closed or pending before it writes open, i though it was going to be easy to add two ifs but it doesn't work. Thanks

Comment: If Target.Address = "$E$2" And Target.Value <> 1 And Range("I2").Value <> "closed" And Range("I2").Value <> "pending" Then Range("I2").Value = "open"

Comment: It work the first part but if on i2 i have already closed or pending as values when i put some value on e2 it change to open. Is like it only take the first condition